# Remove letter off the end of SVN Version number

Tags: svn, ant, build.xml

I have the target to display which working copy I have

```
<target name="svnversion">
        <exec executable="svnversion" outputproperty="svnversion" />
        <echo message="SVN Version: ${svnversion}" />
    </target>
```

I'm wanting it to return the number without an M or an S at the end, regardless of whether or not that is the case, so if the output above is: `17349M`, I would like it to return `17349`.  I have attempted [this answer on a different SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/144308/117964). However, I figure that even if that did work, it would cut the end number off in the case that an M or S didn't exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You must to keep in mind **all** possible versions of output: it's more than just trailing "M" or "S". From svnversion help

> ```
> If the working copy is unusual the version identifier will be more complex:
>
>    4123:4168     mixed revision working copy
>    4168M         modified working copy
>    4123S         switched working copy
>    4123P         partial working copy, from a sparse checkout
>    4123:4168MS   mixed revision, modified, switched working copy
> ```

and you have to process all forms

2. Technically, piping to [grep](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#Character-Classes-and-Bracket-Expressions) will allow you to detect, which type of WC your have
3. After all, read [about](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html) [sed](http://www.funtoo.org/Sed_by_Example,_Part_1) which will allow you to perform *any* needed transformation, if you will be able to describe it

Answer (score 0):

An [`<outputfilterchain>`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/redirector.html) can capture the output of an `<exec>` task, transform the output, and save the results in a property. For example...

```
<fail unless="wc.dir"/>
<exec executable="svnversion" outputproperty="my-svnversion" failonerror="true">
    <redirector>
        <outputfilterchain>
            <tokenfilter>
                <replaceregex pattern="^(\d+)[MS]$" replace="\1"/>
            </tokenfilter>
        </outputfilterchain>
    </redirector>
    <arg value="${wc.dir}"/>
</exec>

<echo>my-svnversion: ${my-svnversion}</echo>
```

To test this script, I created an SVN working copy with a modified file...

```
$ svn st
M       test.txt
```

...and verified what svnversion usually returns...

```
$ svnversion
1M
```

Running the Ant script then reported...

```
run:
     [echo] my-svnversion: 1
```

Note that this script doesn't handle the "mixed revision working copy", "mixed revision, modified, switched working copy", or the "partial working copy, from a sparse checkout" possibilities mentioned in the answer by Lazy Badger.